# Loadbalancing settings via spring AWS libraries for multiple RDS Read Only Replicas

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

If there are multiple read replicas, where load balancing related settings can be specified when using spring AWS libraries.

Comment: What load balancer are you talking about? AWS Load Balancer?

Comment: I am not talking about AWS Load balancer...here context is Spring AWS, if there are more than one read replicas, in this case which algorithm spring uses to distribute calls to these read replicas.

Answer (score 0):

Read replicas have their own endpoint address similar to the original RDS instance. Your application will need to take care of using all the replicas and to switch between them. You'd need to introduce this algorithm into your application so it automatically detects which RDS instance it should connect to in turn. The following links can help:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.Replication.html#Overview.ReadReplica

Comment: I know, it can be done inside the application when you are not using any framework. Here my question is, when we use Spring AWS and read-replica-support set to true, which algorithm it uses for load balancing in case of multiple read replicas.
Reference: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_read_replica_configuration

Comment: It uses the default Algorithm Round Robin.

Comment: Could you please provide me any documentation reference for the same ?